# microphone permissions always denied in Firefox for Android in my environment, but not other platforms

Tags: javascript, android, firefox

I am developing an audio recorder. A week or so ago it stopped working on Firefox for Android, tested on multiple devices. It works fine in the Desktop version of firefox. I've pinpointed the problem down to a permissions issue. When I call:

```
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(function(stream) {
          /* recording stuff happens */
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log("error: ",err)
        })
```

I get the error:

```
MediaStreamError
​
constraint: ""
message: "The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context."
name: "NotAllowedError"
stack: ""
```

However if I run the same codeblock in the console of *any other website* I don't get this error.

This is also clearly related to microphone permissions. When I run this codeblock in the console on other websites I am prompted to give firefox permission to record. But for some reason in my website I never see such a permission box.

I originally thought this was because I changed something in my settings in Firefox for Android, but when I tested this on *other phones* running FF for Android, it also doesn't work! Something about my environment is clearly affecting this. But I am stumped as to where to start looking. Are there any hypotheses as to what's going on here?

Edit: some more details that may be relevant to this problem, this was developed with node.js and deployed through Heroku. It was working fine on mobile a week ago but this permissions issue popped up without any changes to the codebase...Happy to supply any further details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using HTTPS on my phone. Turns out you need to use HTTPS to call getUserMedia() on your phone but you can use HTTP on desktop. Explains the discrepancy and the other sites I was using that prompted for mic permissions also used https

Answer (score 0):

Enter "about:config" in the address bar and change the settings "media.devices.insecure.enabled" and "media.getusermedia.insecure.enabled" to true.

This should be done for testing only. If Firefox is your primary browser, I don't recommend to change these settings for security reasons.